# Change link jquery from local to web

Tags: jquery, magento-2.0.7

This is link jquery in my local

```
../pub/static/frontend/../../en_US/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

and I want change to

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
```

Anyone help me?

Comment: which place you want to call this file?

Comment: i want call them at all page

Answer (score 1):

**app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" src_type="url" />        
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: it can add a new link on my page but not replace this: ../pub/static/frontend/../../en_US/jquery/jquery.min.js. And I do not know find it. please help me